# Как автоматически переопределить id элементов в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [1] => хомяк
    [5] => собака
    [8] => макака
)
```

Нужно превратить его в такой:

```
Array
(
    [0] => хомяк
    [1] => собака
    [2] => макака
)
```

Comment: [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)

Comment: @hindmost Оформи свой комментарий как ответ

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach($arr1 as $k){
    $arr2[] = $k;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]